# Generic array group by using lambda

Tags: php, array

This is K.I.S.S, but how about some error and misuse control? I am wishing it were .NET.

```
<?php

function array_group_by($arr, $key_selector) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($arr as $i){
        $key = $key_selector($i);
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
            $result[$key] = array();
        }
        $result[$key][] = $i;
    }
    return $result;
}

 $data = array(
        array(1, "Andy", "PHP"),
        array(1, "Andy", "C#"),
        array(2, "Josh", "C#"),
        array(2, "Josh", "ASP"),
        array(1, "Andy", "SQL"),
        array(3, "Steve", "SQL"),
    );

$grouped = array_group_by($data, function($i){  return $i[0]; });

var_dump($grouped);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using the `[]` syntax for adding array items, allows PHP to create the array as necessary. Thus you can scrap the `if` statement for a modest performance increase off 10 to 15% in my own testing. (Unlike if you used [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) which would throw a warning instead.
2. The unused `$group` variable appears to be a mistake, as the function appears to fulfill it's purpose without it. Code reduced to:

   ```
   function array_group_by($arr, $key_selector) {
     $result = array();
     foreach ($arr as $i) {
       $key = $key_selector($i);
       $result[$key][] = $i;
     }
     return $result;
   }
   ```
3. At this point, the `$key` *could* also be left out, but it's almost free in terms of performance, and increases readability, so I left it there.
4. I'm not sure how much misuse and error handling you need, the function is pretty simple. I would stick with type-hinting the arguments. `array` is available since PHP 5.1, `callable` since 5.4. The signature would become

   ```
   function array_group_by(array $arr, callable $key_selector);
   ```

   Then PHP will at run-time throw a fatal error at anyone trying to call the function with incorrect parameters. Generally I think that's good, but in this particular case, it introduces a problem.
   `array('class_A', 'method_B')`, is a valid callable, that won't work with with the fast `$function($arg);`. For any valid callable to get executed, you need to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) instead, which is a bit slower. In my testing however, the removal of the `if` has bigger impact than the use of `call_user_func()`, so if this isn't performance critical, stick with callable and `call_user_func()`.

Final code:

```
function array_group_by(array $arr, callable $key_selector) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($arr as $i) {
    $key = call_user_func($key_selector, $i);
    $result[$key][] = $i;
  }  
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Type hinting... Yeah I am rusty on PHP. This is a great answer. I'll give others a chance to bite before marking it as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: How about an array walk instead of a foreach? Will that just make it less readable?

Comment: I pondered various native array functions for a moment, but I think most (all?) of them want to act directly on the individual elements of the array, which makes them unsuitable to use when you want out data with a different structure than the in data. I could be wrong on this though.

Comment: I changed "callable" to "closure"

Comment: 1) I had no idea that was valid, and 2) I can't find that documented under [type_hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). What in the world!? It behaves as expected though. Cool, I learned something new.

Comment: I got an error when I had it as callable instead of closure. We must be using a different version. The error is that when passing in an anonymous function, it says "expected callable, got closure"